# How to create a spiral matrix in numpy python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation

Output should be n rows * n cols with numbers from n to n ** 2 (for example 5 to 25) in a spiral starting from the upper left corner and twisted clockwise,
as shown in the example (here n=5):

Sample input 5

######################

Sample Output:

1      2   3   4   5

16    17   18  19  6

15    24   25  20  7

14    23   22  21  8

13    12   11  10  9

Comment: You should checkout https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix-ii/. I think it might be similar to your question.